# linux + pvresize fail on "Failed to find physical volume"

Tags: linux, lvm

after we increase the VM disk from 2G to 20G , and reboot 
we need to do pvresize  on the /dev/sdc

but we get the following errors during pvresize

```
pvresize -v /dev/sdc
Using physical volume(s) on command line.
Found same device /dev/sda2 with same pvid v0593aKiKU9embSTbxByMzS95kjChr0m
Failed to find physical volume "/dev/sdc".
0 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
```

Comment: What the hell? OK, back up. Why is your physical volume ID duplicated? Is your PV really sdc, or sdcX (where X is the partition number)?

Comment: Dealing with a similar issue but I suspect it's happening because the volume in question isn't an LVM volume.